# R: using if/else to append column in a list with objects of varying lengths

Tags: r, function, if-statement, lapply, divide-by-zero

I am trying to append a column of values to the elements of an R list, where each element is of varying length. Here is an example list foo:

```
A   B   C   
1   1   150
1   2   25
1   4   30
2   1   200
2   3   15
3   4   30
```

First, I split foo into list foo with elements based on each unique value of A. Now, I would like to write a function that a) the sums the values of C for each value of A, but that b) excludes B when B == 4. c) The sum is appended as a new column D, and d) C is divided by D to yield a proportion (column E). Ultimately, it would be combined in a new df to look like:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   1   150 175 0.857
1   2   25  175 0.143
1   4   30  175 0.171
2   1   200 215 0.930
2   3   15  215 0.070
3   4   30  0   0/NA
```

However, I'm having problems because in some cases, for a given value of A, there are only cases when B == 4 (here, where A == 3), so when I try to divide C by D, I get error messages.

Is there a way to incorporate an if/else statement into the function so that when A is unique and the only possible value of B is 4, the operation is skipped and a default non-zero value is placed in the appended column?

Subsetting the df to excluded cases where B == 4 makes later operations more difficult, but including cases where B == 4 makes the sum/proportion calculate inaccurate.

Any help is appreciated! Here is the current code:

```
goo <- lapply(foo,function(df){
  df$D <- sum(df$C, na.rm = TRUE)
  df$E <- df$C / df$D
  ###  .....
  df
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
newfoo <- foo %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(D = sum(C[B != 4]),
         E = C/D)
#newfoo                   # the resulting data.frame
#Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
#Groups: A
#
#  A B   C   D          E
#1 1 1 150 175 0.85714286
#2 1 2  25 175 0.14285714
#3 1 4  30 175 0.17142857
#4 2 1 200 215 0.93023256
#5 2 3  15 215 0.06976744
#6 3 4  30   0        Inf
```

Or if you want to avoid `Inf`, you can use `ifelse` like this:

```
newfoo <- foo %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(D = sum(C[B != 4]),
         E = ifelse(D == 0, 0, C/D))
#Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
#Groups: A
#
#  A B   C   D          E
#1 1 1 150 175 0.85714286
#2 1 2  25 175 0.14285714
#3 1 4  30 175 0.17142857
#4 2 1 200 215 0.93023256
#5 2 3  15 215 0.06976744
#6 3 4  30   0 0.00000000
```

Answer (score 4):

And a `data.table` (possible) solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(foo)[, D := sum(C[B != 4]), by = A][, E := C/D]
# foo
#    A B   C   D          E
# 1: 1 1 150 175 0.85714286
# 2: 1 2  25 175 0.14285714
# 3: 1 4  30 175 0.17142857
# 4: 2 1 200 215 0.93023256
# 5: 2 3  15 215 0.06976744
# 6: 3 4  30   0        Inf
```

Not sure what you want to put into column `E` when `A == 3`, but you can use `is.finite` for it and avoid messing around with `ifelse`, for example (replacing with a zero)

```
setDT(foo)[, D := sum(C[B!=4]), by = A][, E := C/D][!is.finite(E), E := 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using the `base` package.

First, ensure that the data are modeled appropriately by converting `A` into a factor if it is not one already:

```
df$A <- factor(df$A)
```

Now, we can compute `D` using `tapply`, which iterates groupwise and returns the result as a `t`able. We do this `with` the `subset` of `df` where `B != 4`.

```
df$D <- with(subset(df, B != 4), tapply(C, A, sum))[df$A]
```

Note that since `A` is a factor, we can index into the table to perform the merge. Now we can use `ifelse` to compute `E`:

```
df$E <- with(df, ifelse(is.na(D), 0, C/D))
```